# NAudio - Create a synchronous version of WaveOut.Stop

Tags: synchronization, naudio

I use `WaveOut` to play audio in WPF app. I need to run some code after I manually stop playing audio. Putting the code right after `WaveOut.Stop()` causes problems, since `WaveOut.Stop()` does not stop the audio immediately. When I put the code in the event handler of `WaveOut.PlaybackStopped`, it works fine.

However, I would like to have a cleaner design, by creating a method that stops the audio and returns only after it really stops, i.e, after `WaveOut.PlaybackStopped` is fired, like:

```
WaveOut_.StopCompletely();
DoSomething();
```

I don't want to `await` for the audio to stop, because if I do this I will have to decorate a lot of my code base with async-await. Instead, I would like to block the UI. I don't care to block, since it's very short time. I have tried using `AutoResetEvent`, as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243007/289415), but for some reason it blocks forever. I also tried using `TaskCompletionSource` (without awaiting) as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900697/289415), but this returns immediately.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

a simple approach is just to sleep until the playback state is stopped:

```
while (player.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to wait exactly the time it takes to stop, not more than that.

Comment: Also, using 'Thread.Sleep' doesn't work because it blocks the current thread (the GUI thread), so 'WaveOut.PlaybackStopped' is never fired.